# How do I check the permission of an URI that has been send with an intent?

Tags: android, permissions

I have tried the following but this always returns PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED although I
know that I have the right to read the file. Any ideas?

```
Uri uri = (Uri) intent.getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);

// check uri permissions but does not work
int perm = checkUriPermission(uri , "r", null,
        Binder.getCallingPid(), Binder.getCallingUid(),
        Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
if (perm == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
    "No permissions to read the file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`r` is not a permission. Try passing `null` for the second parameter, or use the version of `checkUriPermission()` that skips the two String parameters you have in the second and third positions.

Comment: Ah, now I got it. I always have to know the permission I want to check. But that is not what I want. I want to know if I can read the file. Sometimes there are other apps that allow to send the file but my app does not have the permission to read them. So I have to catch the SecurityException...